# Upgrade Kafka version from 2.7 to 3.6.1 and strimzi operator version from 0.24 to 0.39

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

We have kafka running on K8s version 1.26. we want to update kafka version from 2.7 to 3.6.1 and also strimzi operator 0.24 to 0.39.
I am new to Kafka and would like to know is it possoble to do a direct upgrade skipping versions in between.

I want to know the upgrade strategy

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. I know that direct upgrade from Strimzi 0.22 or earlier to 0.39.0 is not possible. and also strimzi has this statement in their release updated

```
Important: From Strimzi 0.40 on, we support only Kubernetes 1.23 and newer. Kubernetes versions 1.21 and 1.22 are no longer supported.
```

and you are already on version 1.26 of K8s. So there is no issue with the platform version.

Note that there are number of changes introduced by strimzi like StrimziPodsets instead of statefulsets. then there is UTO e.t.c

Strimzi release list is here: https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/releases